# please how to convert this type of table to a simple php table

Tags: wordpress

please how to convert this type of table to a simple php table 
this table is in the wp_option when i insert a php array into an option

```
a:6:{s:6:"ex1";a:0:{}s:9:"ex2";a:0:{}s:7:"ex3";a:0:{}s:8:"ex4";a:0:{}s:10:"ex5";a:0:{}s:12:"ex6";a:0:{}}
```

please who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: php doesn't have tables.  what do you mean?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/how-to-extract-data-from-a-post-meta-serialized-array

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to unserialize the data you are getting - there is a wordpress function for that: [maybe_unserialize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) or the direct PHP function [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) however neither work with the example string you pasted as its in an invalid format. But try them directly in your code and see.

Comment: unserialize this reuturn false can you help me to unserialize this 
http://pastebin.com/GUWccGFC